# TriggerEvent in OMS Not DMS

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-dms

I've been trying to substitute for a deprecated method which was in the OMS for 6.4 which is "TriggerEvent". I now get the following error with the following code. in the new DMS 6.5. I'm not sure what's the correct new method.

```
var tracker = Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Visitor.CurrentVisit.CurrentPage;
if (tracker != null)
{
    string dataXml = Review_Module.sitecore_modules.Review_module.Classes
         .AnalyticsHelper.FillDataField(new string[]
              {
                 "Title", title, "Description", description, "Rate", rate
              });

    PageEventData eventData = new PageEventData("Review");
    eventData.Data = dataXml;
    VisitorDataSet.PageEventsRow pageEventsRow = Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.CurrentPage.Register(eventData);
    Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Submit();
```

Error

```
[PageEventDefinitionNotFoundException: The page event definition Review could not be found.]
   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.DataSets.PagesRow.Register(PageEventData data) +170
   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.DataSets.PagesRow.Register(String name, String text, String dataKey, String data) +127
   ReviewModule.Nicam_Modules.Review_module.Controls.Review.ReviewClicked(Object sender, EventArgs e) +808
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnClick(EventArgs e) +111
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +79
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +175
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565
```

Working Code in 6.4 OMS

```
 string dataXml = Review_Module.sitecore_modules.Review_module.Classes.AnalyticsHelper.FillDataField(new string[]
       {
          "Title", title, "Description", description, "Rate", rate
       });
       tracker.CurrentPage.TriggerEvent("Review", "Review: \"" + Sitecore.Context.Item.Name + "\"", string.Empty, dataXml);
       tracker.Submit();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I finally had a chance to get back here and update this post. I was able to get this working in 6.5. Not sure if they are going to update the module or if they have plans to.

Firstly,
I had to remove the call to the TriggerEvent method. As well,the AnalyticsTracker no longer exists. It now uses PageEventData and Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.CurrentPage;

```
var tracker = Sitecore.Analytics.AnalyticsTracker.Current;
if (tracker != null)

{

string dataXml = Review_Module.sitecore_modules.Review_module.Classes.AnalyticsHelper.FillDataField(new string[]

{"Title", title, "Description", description, "Rate", rate});

 tracker.CurrentPage.TriggerEvent("Review", "Review: \"" + Sitecore.Context.Item.Name + "\"", string.Empty, dataXml);
 tracker.Submit();

}
```

And replace it with:

```
var tracker = Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.CurrentPage;

if (tracker != null)

{

 string dataXml = Review_Module.sitecore_modules.Review_module.Classes.AnalyticsHelper.FillDataField(new string[]

{
 "Title", title, "Description", description, "Rate", rate
});

 PageEventData eventData = new PageEventData("Review");

 Guid Gu = new Guid();

 eventData.Text = "Review: \"" + Sitecore.Context.Item.Name + "\"";
 eventData.DataKey = String.Empty;
 eventData.Data = dataXml;
 eventData.ItemId = new Guid(Sitecore.Context.Item.ID.ToString());
 Tracker.CurrentPage.Register(eventData);
 Tracker.Submit();
}
```

Also, had to update the SQL for the reviews that were posted for UI public view.

From:

```
 //var sql = @"select {0}PageEvents{1}.Data from {0}PageEvents{1} inner join {0}Pages{1} on {0}PageEvents{1}.PageId = {0}Pages{1}.PageId
 //inner join {0}PageEventDefinitions{1} on {0}PageEventDefinitions{1}.PageEventDefinitionId = {0}PageEvents{1}.PageEventDefinitionId
 //where {0}Page{1}.ItemId = @itemId
 //and {0}PageEventDefinitions{1}.Name = 'Review'";
```

To:

```
 var sql = @"select {0}PageEvents{1}.Data from {0}PageEvents{1}
 where {0}PageEvents{1}.ItemId = @itemId
 and {0}PageEvents{1}.[Text] LIKE 'Review:%'";
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can review the API for DMS on the SDN. There are two docs that I think you should focus on:

- [Engagement Analytics API Reference Guide](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/Engagement%20Analytics%20API%20Reference%20Guide.aspx)
- [Engagement Analytics API Cookbook](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/Engagement%20Analytics%20API%20Cookbook.aspx)